# Slow Stripe API response Laravel Cashier

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using Laravel 5.0 and Laravel cashier ~5.0. I am having incredibly long response times from the Stripe API. I am running on a AWS EC2 in US EAST datacenter currently with 1GB RAM. The server has been setup by Forge with no HHVM. There is currently no SSL installed but we will be getting one before we go public.

```
public function storeCard(Request $request)
{
    $group = Group::find(Auth::user()->group_id);
    $group->subscription('customer_month')->create($request->input('stripeToken'));
}
```

Trace from New Relic in the link below

Call to api.stripe.com taking 2980ms.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCWgO.png

Comment: Please include relevant parts of the trace in your question as text. (So that others can find your question when searching for the problem.)

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to this, does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I have the same issue with Laravel 5.2 in development (local).